# What is forking a smart contract actually mean? How to fork Sushiswap's Sushibar smart conract and implement staking features?

Tags: fork, blockchain, smartcontracts

I understand the theory of what forking a smart contract is, but in practice, how can I implement a forking? Is forking in practical meaning deploying a new staking smart contract as a factory and importing the Sushibar, Sushimaker, ERC20, and other smart contracts that will be useful and deploying them in deploy.ts as the newer version of Sushiswap is in typescript. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4g8jQoZkrY&t=658s) video from EatTheBlocks. Can anyone please explain how to fork a smart contract practically or refer me to some good content that I can understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can fork sushi bar contract and implement staking feature in it for particular days using timelock

```
contract timelock{
uint public constant duration = 30 
days;
uint public immutable_end;
address payable public 
immutable_owner;
```

And refer to eattheblock timelock contract for more details